# Управление очередью при загрузке DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть модальное окно. В нём много изображений. Открывается оно по необходимости, поэтому загружать их при загрузке DOM нет смысла.
Как мне исключить загрузку всех изображений с классом **cover__preview** и при необходимости, например при вызове функции **open_cover_modal()** загрузить?

Comment: `display: none;` в помощь)) Современные браузеры не загружают контент скрытых элементов.

Comment: Что?? Вы серьёзно?? Это не остановит загрузку элементов, а загрузит их вместе с DOM и потом просто скроет их

Comment: Хм, а оказывается все равно загружаются: https://medium.com/frontend-fun/css-how-css-display-none-affects-images-on-page-load-dbdf1aaea820

Comment: На самом деле есть минимум один случай когда этот стиль предотвращает загрузку, но я не помню условия. Если нагуглю их (и если это до сих пор работает), то напишу в ответе.

Comment: Вкратце, что нагуглилось: раньше это зависело от браузера (и видимо, мне чисто повезло столкнуться с такой особенностью), а не от какого-то стандартного поведения. Поэтому, полагаться на такой метод не стоило даже в те времена. Сорри :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант такой:

Записать `src` в `data-src`, а потом когда надо заполнить `src` у картинок 


Вот пример с использованием `JQuery`

```js
$('button').on('click', function () {
  $('img').attr('src', function () {
    return this.dataset.src;
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  display:block;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img data-src="https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-01/1547367999_1.jpg" alt="фото"/>
<img data-src="https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-01/1547367999_1.jpg" alt="фото"/>
<img data-src="https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-01/1547367999_1.jpg" alt="фото"/>
<img data-src="https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-01/1547367999_1.jpg" alt="фото"/>
<img data-src="https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-01/1547367999_1.jpg" alt="фото"/>
<img data-src="https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-01/1547367999_1.jpg" alt="фото"/>
<img data-src="https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-01/1547367999_1.jpg" alt="фото"/>
<img data-src="https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-01/1547367999_1.jpg" alt="фото"/>
<img data-src="https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-01/1547367999_1.jpg" alt="фото"/>
<img data-src="https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-01/1547367999_1.jpg" alt="фото"/>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: Отлично. То что нужно!